# Mantener Etiqueta HTML en angular

Tags: angular

quiero tener una etiqueta que me valida un *ngIf="condición", pero que esa etiqueta persista y no me la elimine de mi body, esto con el fin de que cuando se valide esa condición la pantalla no se mueva verticalmente

```html
<div *ngIf="!this.form.controls['docsArray'].errors?.required" style="opacity: 1">
      <p class="alert alert-danger">Checkbox is required, select at least one value.</p>
    </div>
```

```js
onCheckboxChange(e: Event) {
    const docsArray: FormArray = this.form.get('docsArray') as FormArray;
    // console.log(e);
    if ((e.target as HTMLInputElement).checked) {
      docsArray.push(new FormControl((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value));
      this.selectedData.push(this.recomendedDocs.find((doc) => +(e.target as HTMLInputElement).value === doc.id));
    } else {
      let i = 0;
      docsArray.controls.forEach((item: FormControl) => {
        if (item.value === (e.target as HTMLInputElement).value) {
          docsArray.removeAt(i);
          this.selectedData.splice(i, 1);
          return;
        }
        i++;
      });
    }
  }
```

Este es el codigo que estoy usando, pero el div no tiene persistencia

Comment: podrías poner el código de tu TS en donde hace que se cumpla esa condición?

Comment: Listo, ya lo puse

Comment: tip: busca css visibility vs display.

Spoiler: lo que quieres es `visibility: hidden`